# How does the human body process Bromelain in pineapple? (A meat tenderising/dissolving enzyme)

Tags: enzymes

It turns out pineapple juice can dissolve a jello set, and turn a beef roast to paste.

It turns out this is caused by [Bromelain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromelain), an enzyme sometimes used in meat tenderising.

I'm trying to work out how you can eat pineapple without dissolving on the spot.

My question is: **How does the human body process Bromelain in pineapple? (A meat tenderising/dissolving enzyme)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enzyme is slow acting, so it does not dissolve your mouth, just slightly tenderises it, which is the sandpaper feel that you get on your tongue after eating it. When the pineapple reaches your stomach the enzyme gets dissolved by your stomach acids, so cannot harm you any longer.